# live wallpaper - detecting touches when navigation menu is open

Tags: android

I have a live wallpaper which responds to touch and swipe/move events.

If I press the applications button on my phone, I get a menu with all my installed apps. My problem is that when I scroll through my list of installed applications, it triggers the touch and move events on my - out of sight - wallpaper beneath. The wallpaper is still hogging resources drawing and updating anyway, and while scrolling through my installed apps, it can become slightly sluggish.

I was wondering if there was a way to determine if either: the menu is open, or preferably - whether or not the livewallpaper is *actually* visible or not.

EDIT - I can only think to listen for `ACTION_MOVE` events in WallpaperEngine. If you detect one without `onOffsetChanged` being called then you can assume the menu is open and disable touch events.